# Share progress between fragments

Tags: java, android

I have several fragments. One of them can start IntentService for heavy operation. The question is, what it the best way to get progress/status of that background task from another fragments?

Comment: please check out my answer, it should help you

Comment: Do you use an AsyncTask<> for the background "heavy operation"?

Comment: No, I use IntentService for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something like `callback` mechanism, you can implement Observer-like architecture/pattern for it.

Read about [Observer pattern on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) (with Java samples)

Here is my sample for you:

```
public class ObservableProgress {

    public interface Observer {
        void onProgressChanged(Object newProgress);
    }

    // I do not know the type of your progress
    private static volatile Object progress;

    private static final List<Observer> observers = new LinkedList<Observer>();

    // closing constructor for clear class's api
    private ObservableProgress() {}

    // on each progress change, all observers would be notified about progress change
    public static void setProgress(Object newProgress) {
        progress = newProgress;
        notifyOnProgressChanged(newProgress);
    }

    public static Object getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    // use it to add progress listener
    public static void addObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    // use it to remove progress listener
    public static void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
        observers.remove(observer);
    }

    private static void notifyOnProgressChanged(Object newProgress) {
        for (Observer observer : observers) {
            if (observer != null) {
                observer.onProgressChanged(newProgress);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In general the idea is acceptable. I guess, with some minor changes it will work for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your service you should define static variables that change value based on the status. Then you can read those variables from your fragment.

You can have an int that goes from 0 to 100.

Define it like this:

```
public static int progress = 0;
```

Read it like this:

```
int getprogress = JavaClassName.progress;
```

Comment: It won't work for me. I want my fragments to be notified when the value/status has changed. In your case I need to monitor the value of the static variable manually. In the question I meant something similar to callback mechanism.